# How do I check the limit of creating new dashboards(runs as logged in users) in my SF org?

Tags: administration, governorlimits, limits, dashboard

So my org has paid for increased limits and I need to find out the limits for creating new dashboard

Answer (score 0):

There is limit for dynamic dashboards i.e. 10 in unlimited and enterprise editions. Apart from that I dont think there are any limits for any non-dynamic dashboards. According to this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rd_reports_dashboards_limits.htm&type=5

'Your org can request results for up to 5,000 dashboards per hour.'

Answer (score 0):

The number of Dynamic Dashboards(runs as logged in user) available to an organization depends on the edition. based on the organization edition.

The following are the [default values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rd_reports_dashboards_limits.htm&type=5):

- **Enterprise Edition**: up to 5 per organization.
- **Performance and Unlimited Edition**: up to 10 per organization.
- **Developer Edition**: up to 3 per organization.

(*If required, more dynamic dashboards can be purchased from Salesforce. Details are available in this help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387279&type=1).*)

When creating or updating Dynamic Dashboards, users may receive the following error, ‘**You have reached the limit for dashboards run as the logged-in user.**’  This message means that your organization has no more available Dynamic Dashboards for use. If you are having a difficult time locating all of the current Dynamic Dashboards for your organization, Salesforce has provided multiple options below.

To locate all dynamic dashboards within an organization, [the following methods may be used](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385369&type=1):

- Use Workbench
- Create a report to find all Dynamic Dashboards
- Use an API tool to help you locate all Dynamic Dashboards
- Manually check personal folders